# How to override controller?

Tags: magento2, controllers

If I want to override a controller in my custom module am I able to use existing functionality of default controller in magento 2. 
If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Use di.xml :

```
<preference for="<core controller path>" type="<module's controller path>" />
```

Copy core function and override it, You can use it in your controller.

Comment: I did this. But it is not working. Can I use default execute function of default controller?